# SharePoint 2010 - Need suggestion

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have one datasheet like mentioned below

```
WorkWeek Person1 Person2 
WW1      X       Y
WW2      Z       A
WW3      X       Z
```

Where A,X,Y & Z are members of the sharepoint group.
Required I want display a webpart like this

```
WW1
Image1       Image2
X            Y
```

Next Week the webpart should get updated like this dynamically.

```
WW2
Image3      Image4
Z           A
```

Where this requirement is possible, If possible then pls suggest how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

I can provide you some Logic which may help you to accomplish this requirement.

Create one Visual web part with the user control which has html as per your requirement,

To get the data from the datasheet use the Code to read the data from Data sheet

When you want to display the data for the First week create one varible and maintain it to identify the sequence of week to get from datasheet.

First time When  you access the datasheet set this varibale with your week of year number.

Condition the reading of datasheet with this variable like IF variable is null then assign it the week no of year.,

Check this variable next time you come to this logic that If variable is less than the week no current week no of year then take datasheet last you get + 1 means Datasheet 2 and so on 
..

Sorry for bad english

```
variable : one for DaasheetNo, WeekNo,CurrentWeekNo

assign datasheetNo = Sheet1

If(WeekNo== Null)
{
first time getdata from DaasheetNo (First Sheet)
}
else if(WeekNo < CurrentWeekNo)
{
Get data from datasheetNo +1
}
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

This is called weekly update Webpart in SharePoint.

#### My Idea:

you can set one `CurrentDate` value like DateTime.Today to Current Web properties.also set one more properties which WorkWeek users.  now check

```
         SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
         if (string.isnullorEmpty(web.Properties["CurrentDate"]))
            {
                 web.Properties["CurrentDate"] = DateTime.Today.Tostring();
                 // do the stuff for displying data.
            }
        else 
          {
             if(IFChangeNeeded())
              {
                 // do the stuff for displying data.
              }
            else
              {
                 web.Properties["CurrentDate"] = DateTime.Today.Tostring();
                 // do the stuff for displying data.
        
            }
         }
```

`IfChangeNeeded()` is function which return bool value. this function check that employee need to change on this week.

```
      public bool IFChangeNeeded()
      {
           DateTime PropDate = Convert.ToDateTime(web.Properties["CurrentDate"]);
           DateTime TDate = DateTime.Today;
           
           if(WeekNo(TDate) == WeekNo(PropDate)) // WeekNo is function return weekno from current date.
             {
                return true;
             
             }
           else
             {
                 return false;
             }
      }
```